# vc++, detect button is pressed before clicked

Tags: visual-c++, keypress

Is there a way to detect a button click before it is released?

When double clicking a button in design mode the following method is created:

```
private: System::Void PVT_tickButton_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
}
```

Which is executed when the button is released. I want to run some method when the button is pressed. If it matters, I press the button with "enter" or space bar. not mouse.

visual studio 2010, c++ is used, (and something called CLI, I think)

Thanks!

Comment: If you go to the properties of the button, then events, you should be able to see a buttonpress event or something similar you should be able to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a button, open its properties window and click on the events tab (lightning bolt). If you scroll down you will see a number of different events you can use.

`KeyDown` would fire when a key is first pressed (if you are using the spacebar for example) or `MouseDown` would fire when the mouse is clicked on the button.

Simply double click on either of these to create the function for these events.

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for. The method has to be created like "void methodName(System::Object ^,System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs ^)", after that the method is available in the dropdown next to "keydown", "keypressed", .... Thank you very much!